# How do I force all post images to center align via css?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am now using the Envo Magazine Theme for Wordpress. I switched themes recently. I have a wider post area to work with. However, that means for older posts with smaller images, the images are floating on the left and text is wrapping around the images. 
I don't want any text wrapping around images.

How do I force all post images to be center-aligned and not floating?

I tried forcing the post area to be a smaller width and that takes care of the overflow text, but that defeats the purpose of switching to a wider theme. I can't seem to find the right code to select all post-attached images. Please advise. Thank you!

Here is one example of a code I tried. I wanted to force all post images to be center-aligned with no text overwrap.

```
.single-entry-summary img {display: block; margin: 0 auto;}
```

Comment: can you please just add that code what you have tried ?

Comment: I added a line of code to my original post to show you an example of what I tried. It didn't work though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can't simply select all images on the page, because they are not build with the same structure. You can prevent the text from wrapping around the first image by removing the class `pibfi_float_left` from the span that is surrounding it. Or you can edit the class and remove the `float: left`.

For the other pictures, you need to remove the class `alignleft` from the surrounding div. Or you can edit the class and remove the `float: left`.

To center the images, you also need to add `display: block` to the surrounding span:

```
.single-entry-summary span {
    display: block;
}

.single-entry-summary img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Important note: For all images except the first one, you need to adjust the `width` of the attachment divs (which have an id starting with `attachment`), otherwise they won't be centered. You can do it like that:

```
.single-entry-summary div[id^='attachment'] { 
    width: 1000px !important; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Just to clarify, when you suggest to remove the "float: left" or "alignleft" class, that involves going into the individual post and making the change, correct? The blog has over 1500 posts and some posts have 10+ images. Not all of them are affected (some images were inserted center-aligned), but I was hoping there is a way to make a global change. For example, is there a way to disable all "float: left" on the whole blog?

Comment: There absolutely is a way to disable it for the whole blog. You need to edit your style.css (which is under themes/envomagazine) and remove line 33. Then you need to edit the ppibfi_pinterest.css (which is in plugins/pinterest-pin-it-button-for-images) and remove line 69. That should do the job.

Comment: I just removed line 33 and line 69 from the respective css files, but the post images are still floating left with text wrapping around them.

Comment: Did you add the styles that I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Yes, I added the css code you provided to the "Additional CSS" section within my theme.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions of what I can try? Thank you.

Comment: Try to add the following to your custom CSS section: 
`.single-entry-summary div[id^='attachment'] { width: 1000px !important; }`

Comment: I cleared the browser cache files and all the posts look great now. Your solution worked!! Thank you so much for your help!!